# get specific last day of each month in pandas / numpy

Tags: datetime, pandas, numpy

I have a round about solution to get the last Thursday of each month, the reproducible code is as below:

```
import pandas as pd
start  = pd.Timestamp('2016-07-27 00:00:00')
end = pd.Timestamp('2016-11-18 00:00:00')
dt_range = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start, end, freq='W-THU'))
t = dt_range.groupby(dt_range.dt.month).last().values.astype('datetime64[D]')
```

However, i guess it is somewhat unnecessary to produce range of values and operate groupby on it for get to the last Thursday. I tried

```
dt_range = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start, end, freq='4W-THU'))
```

but this can result in selecting 2nd last Thursday for months with Thursdays in fifth week.

How can i accomplish this more efficiently, preferably at the date_range function itself?

Comment: I think your solution is great, you could always just combine the two lines to step around storing the larger list in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pd.offsets.LastWeekOfMonth` to build your custom frequency:

```
last_thu = pd.offsets.LastWeekOfMonth(weekday=3)
dt_range = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=12, freq=last_thu))
```

The resulting output:

```
0    2016-01-28
1    2016-02-25
2    2016-03-31
3    2016-04-28
4    2016-05-26
5    2016-06-30
6    2016-07-28
7    2016-08-25
8    2016-09-29
9    2016-10-27
10   2016-11-24
11   2016-12-29
```

Comment: superb. I was aware of pd.offsets but did not know, i could use it with 'freq' here. thank you